# The purpose of "exit 1" inside if statements

Tags: bash

I have recently started learning bash fulltime and today I found something I can't fully understand.

I have learned that running tests inside `[ ]` is a good way to determine different things

I am making a script to install all my different bash scripts to collect them in one folder, and to set environment variables to `$HOME/bin` and stuff like that.

But I started the script, and already I have problems.

The following code seems to only output the result of the first test.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# Installs base system
# Running tests


rsversion=0
sysname=rpsys
# Is setup already done?
if [ -e /etc/.rpsysSetupDone ]; then
    echo "Alright... RpSys v$rsversion is allready installed, uninstalling" >&2
else
    echo "No previous install found, continuing." >&2
    exit 1
fi


# Am I root?
if [ "$(whoami)" = 'root' ]; then
    echo 'Error: this script cannot be executed by root'
else 
    echo "okay proceeding" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

However when I look at some other bash scripts, they seem to be done in a similar way, but working.

I commented out the `exit 1` in the first test to see if the `exit 1` exited the entire script, and I thought right (or at least I think so) because when it was removed in the first test the output was the result of both tests.

To figure out if there was any notable differences I also tried to comment out the `exit 1` in the last test, with same result. both tests were running correctly. I tried adding the `exit 1` in both tests but then it seems like only the first test ran.

So my question is, am I using the `exit 1` correctly in my code example?

Comment: Have you read `help exit`?

Comment: The indentation in your code was inconsistent. I've corrected it (and a few other things).

Answer (score 5):

`exit` exits the script.  The argument passed to `exit` indicates the value to return.  Non-zero indicates failure.  If your script is successful, you `exit 0`.  If it fails, you `exit 1`.